# Randomly select the ImageViews from View Array

Tags: android

I am trying to select Random 15 ImageViews out of the 21 from the View array and want to set them as Clickable then the same need to be given to the TextView Array

Here is the code .. how to achieve the same

```
public class HiddenObject {

   Random _randomGenerator= new Random();
   int hudDisplay[]={R.id.HUD_Text_Element1,R.id.HUD_Text_Element2,R.id.HUD_Text_Element3,
                   R.id.HUD_Text_Element4,R.id.HUD_Text_Element5,R.id.HUD_Text_Element6,
                   R.id.HUD_Text_Element7};

   View[] _hudDisplay;
   View[] _hiddenObjects; 
   int NO_OF_OBJECTS;

   public HiddenObject(Context context,View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


           View huddisplay= View.inflate(context, R.id.HUD_Display, null);

           _hudDisplay=GetView.getViewArrays(huddisplay, R.id.HUD_Display);


           NO_OF_OBJECTS=context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.NO_OF_OBJECTS_AVAILABLE_PER_LEVEL);

           _hiddenObjects= new View[NO_OF_OBJECTS];

           random();

   }

   public void setHudDisplay()
   {



   }

   public void random(){

       for(int i=0;i<NO_OF_OBJECTS ;++i)
       {
           while(true)
           {
               Integer next = _randomGenerator.nextInt(GamePlayActivity._hiddenObjects.length);
               _hiddenObjects[i]=GamePlayActivity._hiddenObjects[next];
               Log.d("Print", "Image is " + _hiddenObjects[i].getContentDescription());
               if(!_hiddenObjects[i].isClickable()){
                   _hiddenObjects[i].setClickable(true);
                    break;
               }
           }

       }

   }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for loop your HUDdisplay and   _huddisplay[i].setText(_hiddenObject[i].getTag());

Comment: I achieved that by myself ...but the problem is I need to keep updating the textview on runtime ...